# JQuery Hide() does not hide element when using it in a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've been trying to use `.toggle()` and .hide()` to hide paragraph elements in JQuery. I haven't successfully gotten either to work.  Based on whether or not the button is clicked, the paragraph element should be hidden.

#### DomReady

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").onclick(function(){
    $("#paragraph").hide();
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css"/>
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <p id="paragraph">Click here to hide me</p>
   <input type="button" value="Hide">
</body>
</html>
```

#### Javascript:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    function btn1Down() {
        $("#btn1 ul li").css("box-shadow", "0px 0px 5px rgba(115, 115, 115, 0.60)");
        $("#btn1Left ul li").css("box-shadow", "6px 6px 0px rgba(115, 115, 115, 0.60)");
    }
    function btn1Up() {
        $("#btn1 ul li").css("box-shadow", "3px 3px 0px rgba(115, 115, 115, 0.60)");
        $("#btn1Left ul li").css("box-shadow", "0px 0px 0px rgba(115, 115, 115, 0.60)");
    }

    $("button").toggle(function() {
        $("#paragraph").html("hello");
    }, function() {
         $("#paragraph").html("hi");
         });
});
```

#### HTML

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Firecoding Library</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        <script src="jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script src="jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="Script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p id="paragraph">Click here to toggle me</p>
        <input type="button" value="toggle">
        
        <!--<div id="btnContain1">
            <div id="release"><p>Release</p></div>
            <div id="btn1" onmousedown="btn1Down()" onmouseup="btn1Up()"><ul>
                <li>Button</li>
            </ul></div>
            <div id="btn1Left"><ul>
                <li></li>
            </ul></div>
        </div>-->
    </body>
</html>
```

Clicking on the button does not result in the paragraph being hidden, although I expect it should. I also do not receive any errors in the Chrome dev Tools console.

Comment: No idea why this was voted down, it's a high quality question.

Comment: A few issues that will help us answer your question (and get it re-opened): 1) Your title should explain the problem you'd look for if you were searching on Google. No one would search for "why won't this work with my jquery?" 2) What error messages do you get in the console? What behavior do you observe? What do you expect to happen? 3) If you were to distill the problem with your `toggle` down to one line, what would that problem be? (It doesn't work isn't helpful; telling us what 'it doesn't work' means is).

Comment: Can you show us a reference to this .onclick you talk of?

Comment: Wrong selector: You need `$("input[type=button]")` instead of `$("button")`

Comment: There is no button in the page, therefore `$("button")` will select no one.

Comment: @DarkAshelin Wasn't closed for that reason; was closed for the reasons I laid out in my comment; even if it were a typo, it would be useful to others if it contained words and phrases that would help others find this problem and its answers. Unfortunately this question does not contain anything helpful to others ("Why won't this work" is not helpful).

Comment: @GeorgeStocker `the jQuery hide() dosent work!!` seems fairly self evident to me...

Comment: @bukko because `$("button")` does not exist and if `button`, there is no `button` tag in the markup

Comment: To be fair to the question poster, this problem would not produce an error in the console (jQuery won't produce an error for unmatched selector). Although verbose, the question is answerable..

Comment: Don't have to be a weener about it @GeorgeStocker

Comment: You don't vote someone down because they have made an error in their code. They came here to learn after all!

Comment: @bukko I downvoted the question because it wasn't asked very well, not because the user has an error in their code.  We've got a specific list of things we need for a well asked question. What good would we do if we didn't have methods to encourage users to ask good questions? A downvote is one such method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A "button" element doesn't exist in the HTML, you could give your button an id and try using that in jQuery. Also your `onclick` should just be `click`. Try making these changes:

HTML

```
<p id="paragraph">Click here to hide me</p>
<input id="btn" type="button" value="Hide">
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#btn").click(function() {
        $("#paragraph").toggle(); // hide() works too!
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped me a lot. I will be sure to not make this mistake again and remember thats what the error messages I got mean! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things I see... One is the "button" selector - it will match a  element, but not an  element.  Second thing is the .onclick - as far as I know, that doesn't exist in jQuery.

Try...

```
$("input[type='button']").click(function() { ... });
// or
$("input[type='button']").on("click", function() { ... });
```

**Edit:**
On the .toggle() stuff, it looks like you're missing some arguments (I don't see an overload that takes only a function).  Plus the same selector issue as above.  http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Comment: Thanks I now see what I have done wrong and realize how stupid it was! Must have just had a brain blue

Comment: I meant to say blur not blue